# When I click a link on my site and then mouse out of it, it changes color. What CSS selector would this be?

Tags: css

It only happens in FF too - I have a list of anchors on my site that have a bunch of custom styling.  When I click an anchor and hover, it remains black (the :active style).  But when I mouse away, it turns white for some reason.

I've tried setting the color to:

```
a:hover, a:active, a:link, a:visited {
        color: black !important;
    }
```

to debug, but it's still changing white after the click-mouse-away combo.  What CSS selectors could be causing this?

Comment: edited to show that I tried this :/

Comment: I'm interested in see your website, do you have a link? ;]

Comment: BTW, Do you try clear you browser's cache?

Comment: Yeah, jsbin or it didn't happen :)

Comment: @user1970939 - it's localhost :( and yeah, I did.  I ended up just forcing the styles via Christian's selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to consider for `a` are:

- `a:link`
- `a:visited`
- `a:active`
- `a:hover`

Of the four, it's most likely `a:visited` or `a:active`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but sounds like it probably remains black because you set it to be black in :hover, however :visited could be causing it to turn white.

Check out your :hover, :visited